# cannot get speakers to work on arch linux

Tags: arch-linux

I have just installed arch linux (no DE) on my computer, then installed `mpg123` and `mplayer` to play mp3 from command-line by either of them. But the sound is not coming, what's wrong?
(I did got some errors about sound card etc, but couldn't note them down)

I have `gstreamer` and `pulseaudio` installed already

this is the error I get:

```
Playing: /mnt/ubuntu/home/edward/Music/Infected Mushroom-Artillery www.mp3c.cc .mp3
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mp3: Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (mp3)
File tags:
 Artist: Infected Mushroom
 Album: Vicious Delicious
 Album_Artist: Infected Mushroom
 Composer: Amit Duvdevani/Erez Aizen/K. Hendriks/S. Bunting/Swollen Members
 Genre: Electronica
 Title: artillery
 Track: 2
[ao/alsa] Playback open error: No such file or directory
[ao/oss] Can't open audio device /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
[ao/jack] cannot open server
Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound.
Audio: no audio
```

Comment: It's probably a misconfiguration of one of the nodes (or edges) in this diagram: http://www.tuxmachines.org/images/linuxaudio-1024x690.png

Comment: @Atsby what to do to get proper config ?

Comment: capture the errors to a file, post to pastebin, and link from question?

Comment: Hope you have installed all the needed codecs like `gstreamer`

Comment: @GovindKailas i have already installed gstreamer

Comment: Did you unmute the audio channel?

Comment: @darnir if i delete all characters from command line, i get beep sound when i reach the end of the line, so that means audio channel is unmuted right?

Comment: Nope. That's only the system beep. If your'e using PulseAudio, open pavucontrol and take a look at the all the channels. Make sure none of them are muted.

Comment: @darnir pavucontrol is window program, cant use on commandline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem why I was not getting sound was `pulseaudio` was not running in background. The reason I didn't know that because `pulseaudio` was supposed to start automatically on startup, but it didn't.
After I started `pulseaudo` by `pulseaudio --start` I started getting sound. Now I have to add `pulseaudio` to startup list to get sound every time I start my computer.

Also I was not able to play song from `root` account, but from non-root I could.

Comment: @nwildner sir clear enough now ?